# Is it possible to share code betwee classes that does not have the same parent?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have two classes that are already subclasses of a different parent (due to an external library I cannot change this). However I want to share some common code between them, say for example, code that handles an action after a popup dialog etc. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refactor the shared code into its own class, and include an instance of that class as a field/property within your other two classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-factor the appropriate code into a utilities class, and then have the two classes call it.  As for the iPhoneSDK, you can probably have the utility method be the delegate method itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a category on a common ancestor class. Then both classes could import that Category and call the common code.

Comment: I'd be concerned about this - the OP specified that the classes don't have the same parent, so the only "common ancestor" they may have could be NSObject. I wouldn't want to clutter NSObject with specific categories for something like this.

Comment: I agree that putting it on NSObject would potentially be cluttering things, but it is a valid way to do what the OP wants to do without holding an instance of some utility class.

Comment: Does this method allow the common code to have access to their private variables as if the code is part of a superclass?